# Web Part not working on a page

Tags: c#, dll, sharepoint-2007, web-parts, moss

I am trying to add a Web Part to a page in SharePoint 2007. The code was successfully built (no errors) so I was able to deploy the Web Part as well. However, when adding the Web Part on a paga, I run into the problem that I have to log in again and the page keeps loading. I isolated the issue and it has to do with a method in an external library (blackbox). Any idea how to resolve this? Please note that I have 3 servers.. DB, domain controller and SharePoint farm. EventViewer says the following:

Application tab:

> The description for Event ID ( 27745 ) in Source ( Windows SharePoint Services 3 ) cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer. You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details. The following information is part of the event: #50071: Unable to connect to the database MOSS_Config on VSSQL.  Check the database connection information and make sure that the database server is running..

System tab:

> A process serving application pool 'SharePoint - 45136' suffered a fatal communication error with the World Wide Web Publishing Service. The process id was '412'. The data field contains the error number.

I read that it could also be that some of the registry permissions have to be set correctly, but I am not sure which permissions.

Any suggestions how to proceed on this?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with the database:

> Unable to connect to the database MOSS_Config on VSSQL

Here's what you should check:

- Does the VSSQL server exist?
- Is the SQL Server instance running?
- Is it possible to connect to VSSQL from the SharePoint server?
- Does the MOSS_Config database exist?
- Does the user that is used by the SharePoint process have the necessary permissions?

Also, check the SharePoint logs (in the `(12 hive)\LOGS` folder) for additional information.